# Definition of the adjoint action as a left multiplication on GL(V)

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups

I'm currently reading Hilgert, Neeb, Lie-Gruppen und Lie-Algebren, 1991, which is in some sense a predecessor to Hilgert, Neeb, Structure and Geometry of Lie Groups, 2012. As the book is in German I'll be here a bit more elaborate.

In preparation for the Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula the adjoint map or adjoint representation $Ad$ is defined. The authors consider the matrix Lie group $G = GL(n, \mathbb{K})$ and its associated Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g} = \mathfrak{gl}(n, \mathbb{K})$ and define
$$
 Ad(g) X = gXg^{-1}
$$
with $g\in G$ and $X \in \mathfrak{g}$. One shows that
$$
 Ad: G \to GL(\mathfrak{g})
$$
where $GL(V)$ denotes the invertible linear maps on a vector space $V$. Proposition I.4.2 states that $Ad$ is a differentiable group homomorphism and a bit more.

In the proof the differentiability of $Ad$ in 1 is shown and than it is claimed that the differentiability in any other point can be derived from the fact that
$$
 Ad = \lambda_{Ad\ h} \circ Ad \circ \lambda_{h^{-1}}
$$
where $\lambda_h$ is the left action on $G$; $\lambda_h g = hg$. Here, I reproduce the formula as shown in the book. But I assume that it should be $Ad(h)$ and is just a minor inconsistency in the notation.

Now, reading the formula from the right, I understand the first two parts, giving
$$
 g \mapsto h^{-1} g \mapsto h^{-1} g \bullet (h^{-1} g)^{-1} = h^{-1} g \bullet g^{-1} h
$$ 
where the bullet should indicate that the expression is a map. Of course, the map
$$
 h^{-1}g \bullet g^{-1}h \mapsto h h^{-1} g \bullet g^{-1} h h^{-1} = g \bullet g^{-1}
$$
does exactly what is needed for the result. But would that be the correct understanding of the definition of $\lambda_{Ad(h)}$? Or is it the consequence of a definition I don't see? To boil it down to my fundamental lack of understanding:

What would be the definition of $\lambda_{Ad\ h}$ on $GL(\mathfrak{g})$?

If there is a related question math.SE I have overlooked with an answer that also solves my problem a hint to that answer is of course sufficient. Otherwise, any help is appreciated.

Comment: So what do you think $\lambda_{\mathrm{Ad}(h)}$ is? I thought that for each $h \in G$, $\lambda_h: G \to G$, and so I don't really understand how you "put in" an $\mathrm{Ad}(h)$ into $\lambda$.

Comment: @Joppy: Thanks for your comment. But it seems I miss your point. My question is in what sense I can understand $\lambda_{Ad h}$ as a "left multiplication" on $GL(\mathfrak{g})$.

Comment: The only thing that makes sense for me is for $\lambda_{\mathrm{Ad}(h)}$ to be the conjugation map $GL(\mathfrak{g}) \to GL(\mathfrak{g})$, $X \mapsto \mathrm{Ad}(h) \,X \,\mathrm{Ad}(h)^{-1}$

Comment: @Joppy. Thanks for insisting; my math being now quite rusty, I was a bit uncertain. Returning to the definitions I think I got it. $GL(V)$ is the group of ($\mathbb{K}$-linear) automorphisms with the composition of functions as the group operation. Thus, given two functions $f_1, f_2$ the left action would be $\lambda_{f_2} f_1 = f_2 \circ f_1$. Applying this to $Ad(h)\in GL(V)$ and $GL(V)\ni f: X \mapsto g X g^{-1}$ we get $\lambda_{Ad(h)} f (X) = Ad(h) \circ f (X) = h g X g^{-1} h^{-1}$. This gives now what was expected.